# Typcasting [AnyObject] read from Firebase to [String] Swift

Tags: swift, string, firebase-realtime-database, anyobject

I have created a list of Locations in Firebase and I'm trying to read it in my iOS application and then view it as a PickerView.

[firebase locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA4rk.png)

Below is how I read the data.

```
 ref.child("locations").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            self.listOfLocations = snapshot.value as! [String]
        })
```

code for PickerView

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfLocations.count;
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return listOfLocations[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        selectedLocation = listOfLocations[row]
    }
```

However, I get an error where the program stops the execution at the snapshot line.

The problem seems to me that the read data is of type AnyObject and in the PickerView I need String. Typecasting [AnyObject] to [String] is not working with me.

I would appreciate helps in solving this.

Comment: did you just try to print snapshot value?

Comment: printing the snapshot value before typecasting works, but if I typecast it nothing is printing

Comment: show us that output please, that is definitly not array of strings

Comment: you told that  
printing the snapshot value before typecasting works
 and now you are getting error?

Comment: so you get nil snapshot, you should look for problem in observeSingleEventOfType method, why do you get nothing from there

Comment: I get ..Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0) Also printing output [] However if I declare a value getLocations:[AnyObject]=[] . . . self.getLocations = snapshot.value as! [AnyObject] print("(self.getLocations)") the output is [<null>, OMAN, UK, USA, GERMANY] Sorry for posting and editing I press enter by mistake.

Comment: you are making self.getLocations = snapshot.value as! [AnyObject] in the same method? show some more code where it is working

Comment: `var getLocations: [AnyObject] = []
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
       
        ref.child("locations").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

           self.getLocations = snapshot.value as! [AnyObject]
            print("\(self.getLocations)")
        })`

Comment: This one works to read the Value, but I cannot pass it to the PickerView title of Row

Comment: why you cannot pass that to picker? just cast it to string

Comment: when casting it to string it is not appearing! That is my problem

Comment: can you tell me how do you cast it to [String]? I use `listOfLocations = getLocations as! [String]` but it does not work

Comment: cast as string when you are trying to use that, earlier just keep as [AnyObject]

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean.